How to set up a GPU driver for Nvidia in Alibaba Cloud ECS?
I bought a new ECS with GPU from Alibaba Cloud and follow their default driver installation.

I followed the instructions here.
For Step 2: Install the Tesla driver, after run following command:
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxxx.run

Then I get this warning.

What should I do? What are the next steps?

Probably already installed. There's a procedure to check that in your own linked instructions.
